# How to disable method recommendations in Eclipse Luna's Quick Fix popup?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-luna

Since updating to Eclipse Luna, I'm getting this strange method recommendations when I press `Ctrl + 1` to open the quick fix popup. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

What I actually want is just this:

[image]

Is there a way to disable the blue entries? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to disable call-chain completion but you can hide the entries.
In Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions > Chains set "Minimum chain length" larger than "Maximum chain length".

Comment: Uninstall is not enabled when code recommenders is prepackaged (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Luna) and there is no option to turn off "chains" completely, so this answer is the best workaround there is.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.1.11 of Code Recommenders(released on December 3rd, 2014), the chain proposals are sorted below other quick-fix proposals. So you don't need to deactivate or deinstall anything.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems you have the Chain Completion feature of Code recommenders enabled (https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#chain-completion). To turn it off, you can either

1. Uninstall Code Recommenders.
2. Turn the problematic content assist engines off in Preferences: Java/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced
3. Look for the Code Recommenders/Completion preference page, and turn off engines. See also the corresponding manual: https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#preferences